# Prolog lists transforming

Tags: prolog

I want to transform a list in this format:

```
C=[via(A,B,C,D),via(G,T,H,U),via(J,O,L,P)]
```

into the following:

```
F=[(C,D),(H,U),(L,P)]
```

The letters from F correspond to the letters from C.

Comment: Your sample it's a really strange term, since variable C is **shared** to itself (it's a cyclic term). All answers so far just ignored this problem, hope you're aware of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be something like:

```
transform([], []).
transform([via(_, _, X, Y)|T)], [(X, Y)|TT) :-
     transform(T, TT).
```

Answer (score 2):

several Prologs (like SWI-Prolog I'm using here, in library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply))) have maplist:

```
1 ?- [user].
|: transform(via(_,_,C,D),(C,D)).
(ctrl+D here)
true.

2 ?- X = [via(A,B,C,D),via(G,T,H,U),via(J,O,L,P)], maplist(transform,X,Y).
X = [via(A, B, C, D), via(G, T, H, U), via(J, O, L, P)],
Y = [ (C, D), (H, U), (L, P)].
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `library(lambda)` it comes down to:

```
..., maplist(\via(_,_,X,Y)^(X,Y)^true, C, F), ...
```